# Exception handling in CMT stateless bean

Tags: java, exception, transactions, ejb

Is it possible to catch an exception in a CMT(Container Managed Transaction) stateless bean?

The code below wont catch any exeption when I tried it. If I use BMT(Bean Managed Transaction), I can catch the exception. But I want to remain with CMT.

```
@Path("books")
public class BookResource 
{

    @EJB
    private BooksFacade book_facade;

    private Books local_book;


    @POST
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public Response create(Books entity) 
    {
       try 
        {
            book_facade.create(entity);
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Caught database exception");
        }
       return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).build();
    }



 public class TXCatcher
{

    //@Resource
    //UserTransaction tx;
    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TXCatcher.class.getName());

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object beginAndCommit(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception 
    {
        //ic.proceed();
        System.out.println("Invoking method: " + ic.getMethod());
        try 
        {
            //tx.begin();
            Object retVal = ic.proceed();
            //tx.commit();
            return retVal;
        }catch (RollbackException e) 
        {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "-----------------Caught roolback(in interceptor): {0}", e.getCause());
            System.out.println("Invoking method: " + ic.getMethod());
            throw new CustomEx("Database error");
        }catch (RuntimeException e) 
        {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "-----------------Caught runtime (in interceptor): {0}", e.getCause());
            System.out.println("Invoking method: " + ic.getMethod());
            //tx.rollback();

            throw new CustomEx("Database error",e.getCause());
            //throw new CustomEx("Database error");
        }



        //return ic.proceed();


    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It depends what kind of problem you're trying to catch.  You could try an explicit EntiyManager.flush, but depending on your data source isolation level, some errors cannot be caught until transaction commit, and there is no mechanism for catching transaction commit errors for a CMT.  If that's the case, your only option is to use BMT (even though you said you don't want to).  The only suggestion that might make that more palatable would be to write an EJB interceptor that behaves similarly to CMT (that is, inject UserTransaction into the interceptor, and begin/commit/rollback in the `@AroundInvoke`).

Comment: The @ around invoke was my backup plan. I have edited the code above to show it regards another question. I uncommented the transaction parts, as above, but it still works as long as my bookresource bean is annotated with      TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN). My question is, is the usertransaction necessary?

Comment: You should be able to catch a transaction commit failure *outside* the EJB, as shown in your JAX-RS example, regardless of whether the EJB is CMT or BMT.  To answer your other question: depending on the resource manager you're using (e.g., the JDBC driver), you might be able to use a RMLT (resource manager local transaction, e.g., JDBC setAutoCommit(false)) rather than an XA/global transaction, but you lose out on all the benefits of an XA/global transaction: you'll be limited to a single DB/resource, you won't get transaction notifications, you can't use container-managed JPA, etc.

Comment: Could you expand on "You should be able to catch a transaction commit failure outside the EJB, as shown in your JAX-RS example "I tried using the interceptor on the CMT  bean, but I still couldn't catch an error e.g. duplicate primary key exception. The container threw the entire exception to the client, my original problem. Sorry for the multiple questions, i have searched everywhere for a fix.

Comment: Are you saying that the CMT EJB does not throw any exception at all, or it's not throwing an exception handled by your catch blocks?  I expect you would need to catch `EJBTransactionRolledbackException`.

Comment: Its throwing an exception which my catch block is catching. I wasnt able to catch the exception previously.When I try to use a duplicate primary key on my database, I can now catch it in the bookresource class. Before, the exception skipped over my catch block.

Comment: To be clear, when you say "previously"/"now" do you mean CMT/BMT, or did you make some other change that has fixed the problem?  If an exception is skipping over your catch block, is it just a matter of changing your catch block to catch the right exception?

Comment: Its still CMT, everytime a duplicate primary key violation occurred before, it wouldnt go into the catch function. The container threw it straight to the client, showing internal details of the database. I tried catching SQL exceptions, but to no avail.

Comment: So, have you solved your problem? If not, it sounds like a basic misunderstanding of Java exception handling: you can only catch the "outermost" exception (likely EJBTransactionRolledbackException), not the "inner"/causing SQLExceptions.

Comment: I've tried EJBTransactionRolledbackException, still skips over the catch, unless I add @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW). I would leave the exception to CMT, but it displays the database details to the client, not preferable for a rest service.

Comment: What exception is actually being thrown?  Try "catch (Throwable t)" and print out t.getClass(); that's the exception you should be catching.

Comment: ConstraintViolationException for incorrect data sizes and org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException for primary key violations.

Comment: The outer-most exception being thrown is ConstraintViolationException?  That makes no sense to me.  This appears to be well beyond an EJB question, so I don't think I can help you, sorry.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time. I decided to search the database myself and prevent the primary key violation.

Answer (score 0):

By placing the following above my function in my BooksFacade class create function, the CMT created a 2nd transaction within the first transaction. When the exception was thrown from the 2nd transaction, my BookResource class create method could catch it. No need for BMT.

```
@Overide
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void create(Books entity) 
{
    super.create(entity);
}
```

I noted that the annotation only works when placed on the individual methods, by placing it on the class itself wont make a difference.